# Count based on the max status on a given date, with grouped data

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle18c

My sample is a ticketing system, holding entries for status updates and the creation of a ticket.

Fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5ff4600adbab185eb14b08586f1bd29

| ID | TICKETID | STATUS | TICKET_CREATED | STATUS_CHANGED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | other_error | 01-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-20 08.00.00 |
| 2 | 2 | tech_error | 01-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-20 09.00.00 |
| 3 | 3 | unknown | 01-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-20 09.10.00 |
| 4 | 4 | unknown | 01-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-20 09.20.00 |
| 5 | 4 | tech_error | 01-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 09.30.00 |
| 6 | 1 | solved | 01-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 10.00.00 |
| 7 | 2 | solved | 01-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 07.00.00 |
| 8 | 5 | tech_error | 02-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 08.00.00 |
| 9 | 6 | unknown | 02-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 08.30.00 |
| 10 | 6 | solved | 02-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 09.30.00 |
| 11 | 5 | solved | 02-JAN-20 | 03-JAN-20 08.00.00 |
| 12 | 4 | unknown | 01-JAN-20 | 03-JAN-20 09.00.00 |

I want to evaluate the data based on the ticket creation date, and obtain three things for a specific date:

1. **(done)** how many tickets where totally created on the given date
2. **(done)** how many tickets were created in status 'unknown' on the given date
3. **(not done)** how many tickets were totally in status 'unknown' on the given date? Tricky! Because what matters is the status at the max `STATUS_CHANGED` below midnight of the given date.

Desired result for 01.01.2021:

| TICKET_CREATED | Total Created | Tickets created in Unknown status | Total tickets in Unknown status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-20 | 4 | 2 | 2 |

Explanation: on 01-JAN-20, ticket 3 and 4 were in status 'unknown' at end of the day

Desired result for 02.01.2021:

| TICKET_CREATED | Total Created | Tickets created in Unknown status | Total tickets in Unknown status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-JAN-20 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Explanation: on 02-JAN-20, only ticket 3 was in status 'unknown' at end of the day

Current solution for part 1 + 2:

```sql
select ticket_created, 
count(*) as "Total Created",
sum(case when status = 'unknown' then 1 else 0 end) as "Unknown tickets created",
'?' as "Total tickets in Unknown status"
from myTable
where id in
    (select min(id) as id
    from myTable
    where ticket_created = to_date('01.01.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
    group by ticketid)
group by ticket_created
```

Could you give me some hint on how to approach point 3?

Comment: Question. Does  "Total tickets in Unknown status" also needs to count tickets that still have 'unknown' status before the dates you want? *(you might want to change you sample data then)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would achieve your aims, assuming I've understood your logic correctly:

```
with ticket_info as (select id,
                            ticketid,
                            status,
                            ticket_created,
                            status_changed,
                            row_number() over (partition by ticketid, trunc(status_changed) order by status_changed desc) rn_per_id_day_desc,
                            row_number() over (partition by ticketid order by status_changed) rn_per_id_asc
                     from   mytable)
select ticket_created,
       count(distinct case when trunc(ticket_created) = to_date('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') then ticketid end) as "Total Created",
       count(case when rn_per_id_asc = 1 and status = 'unknown' then 1 end) as "Unknown tickets created",
       count(case when rn_per_id_day_desc = 1 and status = 'unknown' then 1 end) as "Total tickets in Unknown status"
from   ticket_info
where  status_changed >= to_timestamp('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    status_changed < to_timestamp('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + interval '1' day
group by ticket_created;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a05ecca3589edd755a28278f07846f9)

You can see that first of all, I use a couple of `row_number()` analytic functions to provide labels for the rows - one labels the rows per id in the order they were changed (which allows us to identify the first row per id, i.e. the ticket created row), the other labels the rows per id and day in descending order (which allows us to identify the last row of the day per id).

Using that information, we can calculate all three of your cases:

1. tickets created on a day - here I've used a count distinct, but you could change it to `count(case when rn_per_id_asc = 1 then 1 end)`, which may well be more efficient and easier to understand.
2. tickets created on a day as "unknown" - here I've used a conditional count: if it's the first row and it has a status unknown, then count it
3. tickets in "unknown" status at the end of the day - here I've used another conditional count: if it's the last row of the day and the status is unknown, count it.

---

ETA: with the logic for the third part being amended to count active tickets with a status of unknown at the end of the day, I think this should do the trick:

```
with date_of_interest as (select start_date + level -1 dt,
                                 start_date + level next_dt
                          from   (select to_date('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date,
                                         to_date('03/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date
                                  from   dual)
                          connect by level <= (end_date - start_date) + 1),
          ticket_info as (select mt.id,
                                 mt.ticketid,
                                 mt.status,
                                 mt.ticket_created,
                                 mt.status_changed,
                                 row_number() over (partition by mt.ticketid, doi.dt order by mt.status_changed) rn_per_id_asc,
                                 row_number() over (partition by mt.ticketid, doi.dt order by mt.status_changed desc) rn_per_id_desc,
                                 doi.dt,
                                 doi.next_dt
                          from   mytable mt
                                 inner join date_of_interest doi on mt.status_changed < doi.next_dt
                          )
select dt,
       count(case when ticket_created = dt and rn_per_id_asc = 1 then 1 end) as "Total Created",
       count(case when ticket_created = dt and rn_per_id_asc = 1 and status = 'unknown' then 1 end) as "Unknown tickets created",
       count(case when rn_per_id_desc = 1 and status = 'unknown' then 1 end) as "Total tickets in Unknown status"
from   ticket_info
group by dt
order by dt;
```

You'll note that I've updated the query to run across multiple days - if the query is only ever going to run for one date at a time, you can replace the date_of_interest subquery like so:

```
with date_of_interest as (select dt,
                                 dt + 1 next_dt
                          from   (select to_date('03/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt
                                  from   dual)),
```

Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e7bbf61a514e5afd6963b6bf9180eec)

N.B. This isn't going to be the most efficient way of doing things; over time, as more and more records are present, the query will slow down. If you can work out a way to easily identify active tickets, especially if you can get that info in an index, then that would be better.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution, unfortunately it is not working :( The column "Total tickets in unknown status" should give ALL tickets in unknown status until midnight, and not only from the particular day. That's why it's so hard ;(

So fo the date 03.Jan, I want to know how many "unknown" tickets there currently are in total.

Comment: So with your current solution, I do not receive correct results if I put the date 02.Jan ;(

Perhaps let's remove the date fully and just output all ticket_created dates to make it more simple?:)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e37f46806096b3e3427c25fa78e70f9e

I have added a new fiddle to demonstrate the problem. "Total tickets in unknown status" does not provide the correct results

Comment: @TeaCup ok, so you want to know on a given day, how many active tickets were in an unknown status at the end of that day?

Comment: yea, "active" as in how many tickets are in unknown status in total from all the tickets that exist until end of that day:)

Comment: Any idea if that’s possible at all?;(

Comment: Of course it's possible! I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that calculates the 3th metric separately.
Then joins them to the metrics you already knew.

> ```
> with cte_ranges as (
>   select id, status, ticketid, ticket_created
>   , status_changed as started
>   , coalesce(
>      lead(status_changed) over (partition by ticketid order by status_changed)
>     , current_timestamp) as ended
>   from myTable
>   where trunc(ticket_created) between DATE'2020-01-01' and DATE'2020-01-02'
> )
> select q.ticket_date   as "Ticket Created"
>      , q.total_tickets as "Total Created"
>      , q.total_unknown as "Unknown tickets created"
>      , endofday.total_unknown "Total tickets in Unknown status"
> from
> (
>   select trunc(t.ticket_created) as ticket_date
>   , count(distinct t.ticketid) as total_tickets
>   , count(distinct case when t.status = 'unknown' then t.ticketid end) as total_unknown
>   from cte_ranges t
>   group by trunc(t.ticket_created) 
> ) q
> left join (
>   select trunc(cast(dt as date)) as ticket_date
>   , count(distinct case when status = 'unknown' then ticketid end) as total_unknown
>   from cte_ranges
>   join (
>     select distinct 
>      cast(trunc(ticket_created)+1 as timestamp) - interval '1' second as dt 
>     from cte_ranges
>   ) cutoff on dt between started and ended
>   group by cast(dt as date)
> ) endofday 
> on endofday.ticket_date = q.ticket_date;
> ```

| Ticket Created | Total Created | Unknown tickets created | Total tickets in Unknown status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-20 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 02-JAN-20 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b7bd92162769f4acd50e701047da7298)*

The trick was to first use `LEAD` to calculate the ranges that a status was active.

Then the cutoff times (last minute of day) were joined to those ranges.
This way you get the days that a status was still active.

Both sub-queries use the CTE.
That way you only need to change the date criteria in the CTE.